# wxpython transparent button

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to design `650px`x`100px` button in an application.

The rectangle contains an icon on the left and a text on the right.

In order to make everything act like a button I was considering adding a transparent button on top of the text and icon but `SetTransparent` has no effect and adding a mask raises an exception as `SetMask` does not exists for `BitmapButton`.

```
bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(650, 100)
button = wx.BitmapButton(panel, -1, bitmap=bitmap, pos=(100, 0), size=(650, 100), style=0)
```

Has anyone done something like this successfully or can suggest a course of action that would help my case?

I have worked with `GTK` in the past and where there is an `EventBox` that can contain anything and have events bind to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxPython doesn't really support that. Transparency is an all or nothing affair where either everything in your app is transparent or none of it is. You can do gradients if you use the PlateButton or the AquaButton though. Or you might be able to do something if you drew the button yourself.

Comment: Can I bind a click to anything else other then a button?

Comment: Yes. You're actually binding wx.EVT_BUTTON to a button. If you just want to catch a mouse button click, then you'd use wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN for the left down click.

Comment: The mouse event? It should work on just about anything. There may be a widget type that eats mouse events, but I don't know which one that would be.